# Wrong CMAKE_BINARY_DIR?

Tags: cmake, freebsd

I have the following trivial CMakeLists.txt (FreeBSD 9.1, CMake 2.8.11.2):

```
project(temp_proj CXX)
message(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This file is located in `/root/trunk/temp`. Since I want to perform an out-of-source build, I create a sibling directory `temp2` and invoke `cmake` from there:

```
root@:/root/trunk # mkdir temp2
root@:/root/trunk # cd temp2
root@:/root/trunk/temp2 # cmake ../temp
/root/trunk/temp
/root/trunk/temp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/trunk/temp
```

How comes `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` are the same?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's your complete CMakeLists.txt? If yes, you should try to see what happens if you add `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)` or `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)` on top

Comment: @Antonio yes, it's the complete file - just for testing purpose. IUUC, `cmake_minimum_required` is not mandatory, but anyway its presence doesn't fix the above issue.

Comment: Have you left a CMakeCache.txt in `/root/trunk/temp` from a previous attempt to run CMake from within `temp` rather than `temp2`?

Comment: @temp2 Thanks, that's it! Now for some reason CMake looks for `/temp2/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake`, but that's already another question :). If I copy this file, the result is correct.

Comment: @IgorR. Maybe you can answer the question yourself with fraser suggestions, this was an interesting one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Fraser suggested, the issue occurred because of `CMakeCache.txt` file, which was left in `/root/trunk/temp`.